# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException : package.ClassName.<init>() Using Class<?>

Tags: java, class

I am instantiating a new class using this code:

```
Class<?> clazz; Object object;

clazz = Class.forname(package.ClassName);//dynamic classes 

object = clazz.newInstance();
```

Now the problem is whenever I run this code, it gives me a `NoSuchMethodExeception : package.ClassName.`

ClassName has a parameter, and I can't remove it since it is a must.

I tried removing the parameter then the error gone (parameter must be always there for some reason).

Why is it working like this?

Comment: Seems like package structure and design and declaration of classes is having some problem.  As per my understanding, you want to create clazz Type instance at runtime, it would be better if you create an Abstract class and in the same package create the rest of the classes extends this abstract class in this way via abstraction you can have proper and full control of your instance creation. NoSuchMethodExeception has relation where your classes are declared, the package structure. OR you can follow this:
Class clazz = Class.forName("fully.qualified.class.name");
A a = (A) clazz.newInstace();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--), the function `Class#newInstance` is only capable of initializing classes that provide a no-arg constructor.

If you want to initialize a type which doesn't provide a no-arg constructor and therefore requires the constructor's caller to provide an argument, you can use the [java.lang.reflect.Constructor-API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html).

```java
Constructor<?> constr = clazz.getConstructor(classTypeOfArgument);
Object instance = constr.newInstance(paramInstance);
```

Note: Using raw types is a rather bad idea in this context as it seems like you already know what kind of types you're dealing with.

@Shankar Saran Singh This has absolutely nothing to do with dynamic type creation at runtime and the code snippet you've provided doesn't solve the author's question at all.

Comment: constructor = clazz.getConstructor(IWorkpageDispatcher.class);
obj = constructor.newInstance(getOwningDispatcher());

Thanks. I have just read the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding your class has no default constructor. That's why you get this kind of exception. So You have to implement default constructor explicitly if you made any constructor in class. This exception comes from clazz.newInstance();

Comment: hmmm as what I have posted, all of my constructor has a parameter...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I also have similar problem in kotlin JPA.
When I use a JPAQueryFactory Projections.fields that needs DTO like below.

```
class AdCampaignDailyStatDTO @QueryProjection constructor(
var id: Long?,
var accountId: Long?,
var name: String?,
var type: AdCampaignType?,
var onOff: OnOffType?,
var status: AdCampaignStatus?,
var budgetLimit: BigDecimal?
```

but it occured 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodException' like you.
Even though many sample code guides that.

```
com.querydsl.core.types.ExpressionException: com.navercorp.groupn.gpc.entity.stats.dto.AdCampaignDailyStatDTO] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.navercorp.groupn.gpc.entity.stats.dto.AdCampaignDailyStatDTO.<init>()
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3349)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:556)
    at com.querydsl.core.types.QBean.create(QBean.java:255)
    at com.querydsl.core.types.QBean.newInstance(QBean.java:222)
```

And I ended up solving problem like below.
It means DTO code needs property initial value that has to define 'null' in my case.
like this.

```
class AdCampaignDailyStatDTO @QueryProjection constructor(
    var id: Long? = null,
    var accountId: Long? = null,
    var name: String? = null,
    var type: AdCampaignType? = null,
    var onOff: OnOffType? = null,
    var status: AdCampaignStatus? = null,
    var budgetLimit: BigDecimal? = null
)
```